# Adding a public class that extends JPanel to JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

Basically as the title says, I'm having a bit of an issue working out how to add a class that extends JPanel to a JFrame.

I've looked on here and on other forums, but no answer that I've tried out has work.

I've also got 3 separate files, my main.java my frame.java and panel.java (abbreviated for convenience)
Apparently it's good practice to have public classes in different files(?) or so I've been told! 
I'd appreciate any help on how to actually add the JPanel to the JFrame, even just a link to some documentation I may not have seen. Also I'm open to any *constructive* criticisms that anyone has about the way I've entered/laid out my code.

Thanks!

main.java

```
public class MyGuiAttempt {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new mainFrame();                

    }
}
```

frame.java

```
public class mainFrame extends JFrame {

    public mainFrame() {
        setVisible(true);
        setTitle("My Game");
        setSize(800, 600);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);    
        add(mainScreenMenu); //This is where I'm clearly going wrong.
    }
}
```

panel.java

```
public class mainScreenMenu extends JPanel {

    public mainScreenMenu() {
        JLabel homeMenuBackground = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("images/my_image.jpg"));
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,600));
        add(homeMenuBackground);
        setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a new instance of your class

```
 add(new mainScreenMenu());
```

Comment: MY GOD IT WORKED. Thanks! It's nice to know I wasn't so far off the answer to begin with!

Comment: Hi @nos, Whilst that worked for me, it's now apparent that when i run my app, the background is very temperamental and only appears every now and then. Is there a reason behind this?

Answer (score 2):

You're confusing *classes* and *objects*. `JFrame`, `JPanel` and `mainScreenMenu` (which should be named `MainScreenMenu`) are classes. To have a concrete frame, you need to create an object of type JFrame. To have a concrete panel of type MainScreenMenu, you need to create an object of type MainScreenMenu:

```
MainScreenMenu theMenu = new MainScreenMenu();
add(theMenu);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've used @nos 's answer though as that seemed to do the trick with less code